# esri/dijit/editing/AttachmentEditor use proxy when viewing attachments

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, attachments

I'm trying to figure out why the ArcGIS JavaScript API AttachmentEditor does not use a proxy when viewing attachments.  I have my proxy set up correctly, and it uses it in every other situation but this.

I'm coming up empty on googling for the answer and have found these threads on Esri which don't give any resolution to it.

https://community.esri.com/thread/47357
https://community.esri.com/thread/176862-attachmenteditor-with-proxy

Has anyone had experience with getting the view attachments to go through a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

esri config has an option to always use the proxy : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.config-amd.html#properties which is set to **false** by default.

```js
require([..., "esri/config", ...], function(..., esriConfig, ...) {
  esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = true;
...
});
```